# Ciclo for javascript - resultado inesperado

Tags: javascript, c#

Estou tendo problemas resolvendo essa questão:

Crie uma função chamada `caloriasDeTrote(`), que recebe por parâmetro o número de voltas representado por um valor numérico e retorne a quantidade de calorias que será consumida.

Por exemplo:

`caloriasDeTrote(2)`
 Deveria devolver 15 onde 5 calorias são da primeira volta (5 * 1) mais 10 calorias da segunda (5 * 2).

Quando faço testes no console com caloriasDeTrote(2) consigo retornar 15 mas quando testo outros valores vem com resultado errado, esse é meu código:

```
function caloriasDeTrote(numeroDeVoltas) { 
 var calorias = 0; 
 for (var i = 1; i < numeroDeVoltas; i++) { 
  calorias = 5 + 5 * numeroDeVoltas; 
 } 
return calorias; 
}
```

Comment: Explique como se faz o cálculo e quais são os resultados esperados

Comment: Creio que é falta dos parenteses, faça assim `calorias = 5 + (5 * numeroDeVoltas); `, o 5 da certo pq na primeira ele pega o 5+5 e só depois ele multiplica. Se fosse outro valor, ele faria 5 +2 e multiplicava, por isso é necessário colocar os parenteses. Se eu entendi certo, é isso.

Comment: Quando o valor de caloriasDeTrote é 2 o código devia retornar 15 onde 5 calorias são da primeira volta (5 * 1) mais 10 calorias da segunda (5 * 2). E quando o valor de caloriasDeTrote é 3 deveria retornar 30 onde 5 calorias sao da primeira volta, 10 da segunda volta e 15 da terceira volta e assim vai.

Comment: Qual a necessidade do `for` então?? é só fazer uma multiplicação, não estou entendendo, se você quer que soma a cada `for`, ou se quer que multiplica de uma vez. @Am44nda

Comment: @Mariana eu ja tirei o for e deixei somente `return 5 + (5 * numeroDeVoltas);` e já fiz muitas alterações e ainda não consegui o resultado que eu quero :(

Comment: Troque `calorias = 5 + 5 * numeroDeVoltas; ` por `calorias +=  5 * i; `

Comment: @Am44nda olha um exemplo que eu fiz. https://jsfiddle.net/hzarquet/

Comment: Não precisa do for, como disse a @Mariana. Nem precisa dos parênteses, a multiplicação é sempre feita antes da adição devido à precedência dos operadores. Tente minha resposta atualizada.

Answer (score 2):

Não tem motivo pra fazer loop aí, a fórmula não é iterativa. A sua função pode ser simplesmente:

```
function caloriasDeTrote(numeroDeVoltas) { 
    if (numeroDeVoltas === 1) return 5;
    return 5 + 5 * numeroDeVoltas; 
}
```

Comment: Acho que é problema xy. Faz do jeito que ela quer com o `for` e depois mostra o porque não precisa do `for`.

Answer (score -1):

Sua pergunta esta confusa, mas acredito que seja isso;

```
    function caloriasDeTrote(numeroDeVoltas) { 
 var calorias = 0; 
 for (var i = 1; i < numeroDeVoltas; i++) { 
  calorias += calorias + (5 * numeroDeVoltas); 
 } 
return calorias; 
}
```